# Why is my Alt+164 giving me ♫ instead of ñ?

Tags: unicode, character

I googled the Alt codes of the characters and I wanted to print the **n** with a tilde. However, when I use **Alt+164**, it gives me a music emoji instead of my desired character. Also when I type **Alt+165**, it is supposed to give me a N with a tilde, but instead I am getting a **gear emoji (☼)**.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: With all fonts?

Comment: It's showing this in my browser though, from the textbox in websites as well as in the address bar in the browser. Not sure about the font parts thoug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gear emoji (☼) has code Alt-15 and the music emoji (♫) has code Alt-14. Not sure why 6 isn't being registered, maybe check if there is no hardware issue?

Either way, if you really need to type the symbols on a regular basis; check out [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), it might help.